# pre_get_posts has php notice when not on CPT archive

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm setting my post archive page to sort by a meta date.  When I'm on the archive page it all works.  However on other pages I get a PHP notice `Undefined index: post_type`.

Here is my function:

```
function rt_webinar_pre_query ($query){
   if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' || $query->is_tax('product_cat') ) {
            $today = date('Ymd'); // Today's date
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC');
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'expiration_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
            )
            ) );
        }  
        }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_webinar_pre_query' );
```

(Yes the post type is Woocommerce Product, but I don't believe this is a woo issue.  I think I've missed something in my function.)

Comment: Which other pages? I'd imagine `post_type` simply doesn't exist in the query vars for the pages showing the notice.

Comment: Hey @vancoder!  any page.  I get the error on normal pages.  If I load other CPTs then there is no error.  Isn't a page just another post type?  I'm confused as to what I would change to eliminate the error

Comment: @rudtek you can get rid of and avoid that notice by using the [`get()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get/) (which uses `isset()`) instead of direct access on the `query_vars` property. So, you'd use `$query->get( 'post_type' )`

Comment: @SallyCJ  That was it.  Thank you.